# Is it possible to wrap an ASP.Net Core web page with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, vue.js, asp.net-core, mobile

I currently have an ASP.Net Core app that uses server-side processing (most importantly for cookie authentication), and some Vue.js to add some interaction.

Is it possible to bundle this type of code into mobile apps with Cordova or do I have to rewrite this page to use XHR and JWT for authentication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. You will basically build a small app with a browser in it that redirects to your server hosted page and show it in the app. Pretty much the same as mobile web site, but you can spread it through App Store and Google Play.

Microsoft have made a [nice guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017) about it too.

If you want to create a real app feeling, perhaps you should move the JS/HTML/CSS to Cordova and communicate using XHR/JWT/WebSockets/etc.